# How to Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04.2, 12.04.3 to 12.04.4, the next Hardware Enablement Stack?

Tags: upgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04.2 32bit. I installed it using LiveCD.

Tomorrow, 23rd August 2013,Ubuntu 12.04.3 is released. I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.2 to Ubuntu 12.04.3 without using any LiveCD. Is it possible? If so please suggest me how can I do.

Actually while using Ubuntu 12.04.2 I have troubled with graphics. My graphics card is Intel i845G 64 MB. When Ubuntu starts it works fine and smooth without any lagging, but after sometime it hangs for few seconds (1 or 2 seconds) with a garbage screen and becomes sluggish. All windows and browsers start lagging and also it is not possible to play any video in any player (VLC, Movie Player, Xnoise, SMPlayer etc..).

I think Upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04.3 could fix my problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

---

I've posted an answer to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04.x to 12.04.4. [Find it here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336527/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-2-12-04-3-to-12-04-4-the-next-hardware-enablement/417581#417581)

Comment: Hey, do you think this is the same problem as I'm having here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/365105/bash-prompt-doesnt-print-until-i-interact-with-console-again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Although normal software updates will bring your system up to 12.04.3**, the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE; the *-lts-raring packages) is not part of those updates ([by policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#A12.04.3_.2B-_13.04_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_Policies_and_Procedures)).

You can install the HWE packages manually, but there are some caveats.

To upgrade use this command line only:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

The **`--install-recommends`** is important. It makes sure that the **xserver** will install completely. Without it, **xserver** will only install partly, and apt will remove most of your system. You do not need to add linux-generic-lts-raring, as it is already recommended by the xserver package, and the **Kernel 3.8** will install too.

When you upgrade like this you may notice that there are configurations left over, among others those of the original `xserver-xorg`. You can purge them (I always do), but beware: this will remove the symlink `/etc/X11/X` that is used to start the `XServer`, so on next boot it won't start. To prevent this, after purging left over configurations, do the following **before the next boot**:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

This will recreate the necessary symlink and everything is fine again.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do anything to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.2 to Ubuntu 12.04.3. Upgrades are seamless using the normal Software Updates within the same release, which in your case is Ubuntu 12.04.

Software updates won't fix your problem with your very old  i845G integrated graphics chipset for the Intel Pentium 4 and Celeron processors from 2002. Any computer that is that old would be better off running a lightweight *buntu flavor, either Xubuntu 32-bit if you've got at least 512MB RAM or else Lubuntu 32-bit if you have less than 512MB RAM.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I fixed my issue (**the lagging problem, that I've mentioned above**). I experimented something new and it is looking good till now.
Here is my story:

1. After updating my repository I noticed that some new packages were listing in Synaptic Package Manager(might be because of Ubuntu 12.04.3 release).
2. Then I installed Linux Kernel 3.8.0 by selecting packages:

   ```
   linux-generic-lts-raring
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
   linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-image-generic-lts-raring
   ```

   and restarted my system. It successfully installed Linux Kernel 3.8
3. Then I installed all -lts-raring packages for Xserver-Xorg using command prompt:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring libxatracker1-lts-raring xserver-xorg-core-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-raring libxrandr-ltsq2 x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring xserver-common-lts-raring
   ```

   it removed already installed Xserver-Xorg packages which was meant for -lts-quantal
4. Then restarted my system again..
5. And then It works great.

Untill now I have not realized any type of problems, running my system for more than 2 hours, running the way as I used Ubuntu 10.10 very well.
I think that it was because of older Linux Kernel and older Xorg drivers.
I also noticed that it slightly enhanced my system performance.
Now I'm able to play games on Wine also (I was not able to play previously), videos are playable as well.

If I will get any type of problem I will reply here.

Thanks again.

Comment: This is not the best way to install the Hardware Enablement Stack for Ubuntu LTS. You're selecting all packages individually manually. Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I didn't select all packages manually. I was just giving an example. When ever you uninstall Xserver-Xorg::-lts-quantal packages it tells about the packages going to be uninstalled at the details tab in Synaptic Package Manager. I just copied all packages renamed it as *-lts-raring then installed. If I'd not have done like this then certainly it would not be able to install Xserver-Xorg::-lts-raring packages.
That was just a trick.. Hope you can understand me.. :)

Comment: I still don't see how this solve the question... You were looking for a way to upgrade to .3 which karel pointed out that you don't need to do anything, but upgrade normally using the update manager, `apt-get upgrade` or anything else, since the system takes care of everything else.

Comment: As I described above also, my real problem was actually not to upgrade to 12.04.3. There was a problem in my graphics card.. It started lagging after few minutes of using Ubuntu. So I upgraded Linux Kernel 3.5 to 3.8 which is actually for lts-raring as described in Synaptic. And also I upgraded Xserver-Xorg for lts-raring. I did not want to download a lot of packages of around 500 MB.

Answer (score 2):

Tomorrow, 6th Feb 2014, **Ubuntu 12.04.4** has been released with new [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#A12.04.4_.2B-_13.10_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_Policies_and_Procedures). It is now available in repository.

> **Those who are willing to upgrade their Ubuntu to next [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#A12.04.4_.2B-_13.10_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_Policies_and_Procedures) can execute these commands:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-saucy
```

> **Those who are willing to install only the [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#A12.04.4_.2B-_13.10_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_Policies_and_Procedures), and don't want to upgrade all packages can execute these commands.**
>
> **Note**: Ubuntu **12.04.2** users can also install **12.04.4** [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#A12.04.4_.2B-_13.10_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_Policies_and_Procedures):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-saucy
```

> And don't forget to restart your system and execute these commands:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-lts-saucy && sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This post was really important to me, thanks, however why did you ignore the official hwe commands like --install-recommends?