# Bash prompt doesn't print until I interact with console again

Tags: command-line, bash

I don't even know where to begin to diagnose this one. Usually, when a command finishes, the prompt prints itself for the next command. However, that is not happening. Hard to explain with words, I'll just use an example:

```
User@Machine:~$ cp /mnt/mountname/directory/textfile.txt .
```

After waiting several seconds (far too long for this operation on a small file) I press `Enter`, and see:

```
User@Machine:~$ cp /mnt/mountname/directory/textfile.txt .
User@Machine:~$
User@Machine:~$
```

So clearly the operation had finished, but the prompt didn't display... until I pressed enter, and then BOTH prompts instantly displayed.

This basically just seems to be a lag issue overall. There is no real predictability on what causes it. I tried upgrading to 12.04.3 (3.8 kernel, lts-raring) and that did not help.

**Update:** Just now I did an `fgrep` on a large text file and it returned correctly. But then I typed `ls` immediately afterwards and THAT didn't print anything until I pressed enter again. This behavior seems inconsistent more than anything else.

**Update2:** At some point I think a number of packages got deleted. I compared `dpkg --get-selected` with the 12.04 manifest; here are the packages that are not installed. Could any of them being missing cause the problem?

```
activity-log-manager-common
activity-log-manager-control-center
appmenu-gtk3
appmenu-qt
apt-clone
archdetect-deb
brasero-cdrkit
colord
cryptsetup
cryptsetup-bin
dmraid
duplicity
ecryptfs-utils
enchant
firefox-locale-es
firefox-locale-zh-hans
folks-common
fonts-nanum
geoclue
geoclue-ubuntu-geoip
gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4
gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0
gnome-online-accounts
gwibber-service-facebook
gwibber-service-identica
gwibber-service-twitter
hplip
ibus-pinyin
ibus-pinyin-db-android
indicator-appmenu
indicator-datetime
indicator-power
indicator-printers
indicator-status-provider-mc5
keyutils
kpartx
kpartx-boot
krb5-locales
landscape-client-ui-install
language-pack-es
language-pack-es-base
language-pack-gnome-es-base
language-pack-gnome-zh-hans
language-pack-gnome-zh-hans-base
language-pack-zh-hans
language-pack-zh-hans-base
libdebconfclient0
libdebian-installer4
libfile-mimeinfo-perl
libfreerdp-plugins-standard
libfreerdp1
libgphoto2-l10n
libmtp-runtime
liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0
libpam-cap
libqt4-sql-sqlite
libreoffice-style-tango
libsane-hpaio
libsnmp15
overlay-scrollbar
printer-driver-c2esp
printer-driver-gutenprint
printer-driver-hpcups
printer-driver-hpijs
printer-driver-postscript-hp
printer-driver-ptouch
printer-driver-sag-gdi
python-dateutil
python-libproxy
python-packagekit
python-reportlab-accel
python-ubuntuone-control-panel
python-zeitgeist
qt-at-spi
remmina-common
remmina-plugin-rdp
remmina-plugin-vnc
rhythmbox-mozilla
rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
sessioninstaller
sni-qt
telepathy-indicator
thunderbird
thunderbird-globalmenu
thunderbird-gnome-support
ubiquity-frontend-gtk
ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu
ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork
ubuntuone-control-panel
ubuntuone-couch
ubuntuone-installer
unity-lens-applications
unity-lens-files
unity-lens-music
unity-lens-video
unity-scope-musicstores
unity-scope-video-remote
usb-modeswitch
usb-modeswitch-data
user-setup
xfsprogs
zeitgeist
zeitgeist-core
zeitgeist-datahub
```

**Update 3**: replying to comment, output of `$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "iU" -e "rc"`:

```
ii  apt-xapian-index                              0.44ubuntu5.1                                       maintenance and search tools for a Xapian index of Debian packages
rc  bugzilla3                                     3.2.5.1-2                                           web-based bug tracking system
rc  capplets-data                                 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu2                                   configuration applets for GNOME - data files
ii  cpio                                          2.11-7ubuntu3                                       GNU cpio -- a program to manage archives of files
rc  cups-driver-gutenprint                        5.2.5-0ubuntu1.1                                    printer drivers for CUPS
rc  esound-clients                                0.2.41-6ubuntu1                                     Enlightened Sound Daemon - clients
ii  evolution-common                              3.2.3-0ubuntu6                                      architecture independent files for Evolution
ii  evolution-data-server-common                  3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1                                    architecture independent files for Evolution Data Server
ii  file-roller                                   3.4.1-0ubuntu1                                      archive manager for GNOME
rc  gdm-guest-session                             0.15ubuntu0.1                                       gdm extension for guest session
ii  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0                          3.4.2-0ubuntu1                                      gir files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
rc  gnome-games-common                            1:2.30.0-0ubuntu6                                   Common files for GNOME Games
rc  gnome-mahjongg                                1:2.30.0-0ubuntu6                                   Mahjongg tile solitaire game
ii  gnome-orca                                    3.4.2-0ubuntu0.1                                    Scriptable screen reader
ii  gnome-search-tool                             3.4.0-1                                             GNOME tool to search files
ii  gnome-system-monitor                          3.4.1-0ubuntu1                                      Process viewer and system resource monitor for GNOME
ii  gs-cjk-resource                               1.20100103-3                                        Resource files for gs-cjk, ghostscript CJK-TrueType extension
ii  gstreamer0.10-gconf                           0.10.31-1ubuntu1.2                                  GStreamer plugin for getting the sink/source information from GConf
ii  gwibber                                       3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3                                    Open source social networking client for GNOME
ii  gwibber-service                               3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3                                    Open source social networking client for GNOME
rc  hplip                                         3.10.2-2ubuntu2.2                                   HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)
rc  irb1.8                                        1.8.7.249-2ubuntu0.2                                Interactive Ruby (for Ruby 1.8)
ii  libarchive1                                   2.8.0-2ubuntu0.1                                    Single library to read/write tar, cpio, pax, zip, iso9660, etc.
ii  libarchive12                                  3.0.3-6ubuntu1                                      Multi-format archive and compression library (shared library)
ii  libaudiofile0                                 0.2.6-8ubuntu1                                      Open-source version of SGI's audiofile library
ii  libaudiofile1                                 0.3.3-2                                             Open-source version of SGI's audiofile library
rc  libbrasero-media0                             2.30.2-0ubuntu1.1                                   CD/DVD burning library for GNOME - runtime
ii  libclass-isa-perl                             0.36-3                                              report the search path for a class's ISA tree
rc  libdrm-nouveau1                               2.4.18-1ubuntu3                                     Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
rc  libept0                                       0.5.30                                              High-level library for managing Debian package information
ii  libffi6                                       3.0.11~rc1-5                                        Foreign Function Interface library runtime
ii  libgd2-xpm                                    2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6ubuntu2                            GD Graphics Library version 2
rc  libgl1-mesa-dri                               9.0-0ubuntu1                                        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
rc  libgl1-mesa-glx                               9.0-0ubuntu1                                        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
rc  libglapi-mesa                                 9.0-0ubuntu1                                        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
rc  libgraphviz4                                  2.20.2-8ubuntu3                                     rich set of graph drawing tools
rc  libgstfarsight0.10-0                          0.0.17-2ubuntu2                                     Audio/Video communications framework: core library
ii  libgtksourceview-3.0-0                        3.4.2-0ubuntu1                                      shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview-3.0-common                   3.4.2-0ubuntu1                                      common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview2.0-0                         2.10.5-0ubuntu3                                     shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview2.0-common                    2.10.5-0ubuntu3                                     common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
rc  libgvfscommon0                                1.6.1-0ubuntu1build1                                userspace virtual filesystem - library
rc  libhpmud0                                     3.10.2-2ubuntu2.2                                   HP Multi-Point Transport Driver (hpmud) run-time libraries
ii  libkpathsea5                                  2009-11ubuntu2                                      TeX Live: path search library for TeX (runtime part)
ii  liblircclient0                                0.9.0-0ubuntu1                                      infra-red remote control support - client library
rc  libllvm3.1                                    3.1-2ubuntu1~12.04.1                                Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libmtp8                                       1.0.2-1ubuntu1                                      Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) library
rc  libnm-glib2                                   0.8-0ubuntu3.3                                      network management framework (GLib shared library)
rc  libntfs-3g75                                  1:2010.3.6-1ubuntu1                                 ntfs-3g filesystem in userspace (FUSE) library
ii  libnuma1                                      2.0.8~rc3-1                                         Libraries for controlling NUMA policy
rc  libodbcinstq1c2                               2.2.11-21                                           Qt-based ODBC configuration library
ii  liborc-0.4-0                                  1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2                                   Library of Optimized Inner Loops Runtime Compiler
rc  libpanel-applet2-0                            1:2.30.2-0ubuntu0.2                                 library for GNOME Panel applets
rc  libpolkit-gtk-1-0                             0.96-2ubuntu2                                       PolicyKit GTK+ API
rc  libpulse-browse0                              1:0.9.22~0.9.21+stable-queue-32-g8478-0ubuntu14     PulseAudio client libraries (zeroconf support)
ii  librdf0                                       1.0.14-1                                            Redland Resource Description Framework (RDF) library
ii  libreoffice-common                            1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4                                    office productivity suite -- arch-independent files
ii  libreoffice-core                              1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4                                    office productivity suite -- arch-dependent files
rc  librpm0                                       4.7.2-1lbuild1                                      RPM shared library
rc  librpmbuild0                                  4.7.2-1lbuild1                                      RPM build shared library
rc  librpmio0                                     4.7.2-1lbuild1                                      RPM IO shared library
rc  libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio                    1.2.14-4ubuntu1.1                                   Simple DirectMedia Layer (with X11 and PulseAudio options)
rc  libsnmp15                                     5.4.2.1~dfsg0ubuntu1-0ubuntu2.2                     SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
ii  libspeex1                                     1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2                                    The Speex codec runtime library
ii  libspeexdsp1                                  1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2                                    The Speex extended runtime library
ii  libtalloc2                                    2.0.7-3                                             hierarchical pool based memory allocator
rc  libtelepathy-farsight0                        0.0.13-1                                            Glue library between telepathy and farsight2
rc  libturbojpeg                                  1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1                            IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libusb-1.0-0                                  2:1.0.9~rc3-2ubuntu1                                userspace USB programming library
ii  libxapian15                                   1.0.18-1                                            Search engine library
ii  libxapian22                                   1.2.8-1                                             Search engine library
rc  libxatracker1                                 9.0-0ubuntu1                                        X acceleration library -- runtime
rc  libxen3                                       3.3.0-1ubuntu11                                     library interface for Xen, a Virtual Machine Monitor
ii  libxres1                                      2:1.0.5-1ubuntu0.1                                  X11 Resource extension library
ii  libxvidcore4                                  2:1.3.2-6                                           Open source MPEG-4 video codec (library)
ii  multiarch-support                             2.15-0ubuntu10.5                                    Transitional package to ensure multiarch compatibility
rc  mysql-server-5.1                              5.1.66-0ubuntu0.10.04.1                             MySQL database server binaries
rc  nvidia-304                                    304.88-0ubuntu0.0.3                                 NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  nvidia-304-updates                            304.88-0ubuntu0.0.3                                 NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  nvidia-experimental-304                       304.48-0ubuntu0.1                                   Experimental NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  odbcinst1debian1                              2.2.11-21                                           Support library for accessing odbc ini files
ii  openjdk-7-jre-lib                             7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2                        OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
ii  openoffice.org-common                         1:3.3.0-7ubuntu7                                    office productivity suite -- arch-independent files
rc  openoffice.org-core                           1:3.2.0-7ubuntu4.4                                  office productivity suite -- arch-dependent files
ii  pax                                           1:20120216-1                                        Portable Archive Interchange (cpio, pax, tar)
ii  php5-common                                   5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                                   Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  python-gtksourceview2                         2.10.1-2build1                                      Python bindings for the GtkSourceView widget
ii  python-pkg-resources                          0.6.24-1ubuntu1                                     Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
rc  python-ubuntuone                              0.3.1-0ubuntu1                                      Ubuntu One widget library
ii  python-xapian                                 1.2.8-1                                             Xapian search engine interface for Python
rc  rake                                          0.9.2.2-2                                           ruby make-like utility
rc  redmine                                       1.3.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                                flexible project management web application
rc  rhythmbox-ubuntuone-music-store               0.0.9-0ubuntu1                                      Ubuntu One Music Store Rhythmbox plugin
ii  rpm2cpio                                      4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2                                  tool to convert RPM package to CPIO archive
ii  smartdimmer                                   0.8b4+cvs20100914-1ubuntu2                          Change LCD brightness on Geforce cards
rc  speech-dispatcher                             0.7.1-6ubuntu3                                      Common interface to speech synthesizers
ii  sysv-rc                                       2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1                             System-V-like runlevel change mechanism
ii  tar                                           1.26-4ubuntu1                                       GNU version of the tar archiving utility
ii  time                                          1.7-23.1                                            The GNU time program for measuring cpu resource usage
rc  tsclient                                      0.150-3ubuntu1                                      front-end for viewing of remote desktops in GNOME
ii  ubuntu-extras-keyring                         2010.09.27                                          GnuPG keys of the Ubuntu extras archive
ii  ubuntu-keyring                                2011.11.21.1                                        GnuPG keys of the Ubuntu archive
ii  unzip                                         6.0-4ubuntu2                                        De-archiver for .zip files
rc  virtualgl-libs                                2.3.2-1~preciseppa2                                 Library files for virtualgl
ii  xdg-utils                                     1.1.0~rc1-2ubuntu6                                  desktop integration utilities from freedesktop.org
ii  zip                                           3.0-4                                               Archiver for .zip files
```

Comment: Did you made any modification in any bash initialization file, like `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu No, and I just looked at it, it looks fairly normal

Comment: And this is happen only when you are using `cp`? What  is the output of this command: `type cp`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu No, it's not only `cp`, it seems to be any command that's not instantaneous. The mount is a network share, and the same thing happens with mv, for example. But I'm finding it harder to reproduce than I thought.

Comment: Is this true for every new terminal you use? Because it has happened to me, but only for specific terminal sessions.

Comment: Can you post your `~/.bashrc` file on http://paste.ubuntu.com/?

Comment: @durron597 Yep, nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu hey I added a list of the packages that are not installed. Any ideas?

Comment: execute this command : `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "iU" -e "rc"` and reply the output you get..

Comment: @SauravKumar Edited it in

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using here (the standard gnome-terminal?). Also, if you drop to a text console (Alt+Shift+F1, Alt+F7 to return), do you see the same behaviour on that?

Comment: @durron597 - have you checked the preferences/settings of your terminal/gnome-console/kde-konsole ? there are different menue-entries ... such for profile, profile-settings and else preferences. Could be that settings of bash-history are set to zero instead of 1000 or 2000 ?

Comment: @JeremyKerr I haven't tried what you describe, but I have no problems when `ssh` into the box.

Comment: Regarding the terminal suggestions, what happens if you 'ctrl+alt+f1', and try the commands there?

Comment: Does this happens with any user? Creating another user does the issue still happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is a bug either in gnome-terminal (I assume that's the terminal you're using), or the graphics / desktop subsystems, or some interaction between them. Is it actual keyboard input that triggers the appearance of the missing line, or does scrolling down e.g. with the mouse wheel do it? I've seen bugs like that before in g-t, the last one I think was to do with switching or creating tabs.

Examples of similarly reported previous bugs:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/881014
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695412

I would suggest trying with a different terminal program (e.g. xterm), and perhaps using a different window manager or desktop environment (e.g. swap between unity and unity-2d), or graphics driver (e.g. swap between nouveau and the nvidia proprietary driver.) Actually chasing the bug in gnome-terminal down and getting it fixed is probably not very likely, sadly.

I very much doubt missing packages are the cause.

Comment: [This turned out to be this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/888666) I fixed it by finally managing to get the latest nvidia drivers to work.

Answer (score 0):

You've some **residual configuration** that should be removed. Also I suggest you to upgrade your system and re-configure the updated packages. So I want you to execute these steps once, I wish it would help you.

1. First open **software Sources** to ensure that you'll be able to upgrade your system without any problem:

   - Execute `sudo software-properties-gtk` in terminal and go to **Updates** tab. `Tick` first two `Check boxes`, and in the same tab for `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version`, select: `For long-term support versions`. Then go to **Other Software** tab and `Tick` first four `Check boxes`. Except first four, either remove or `Untick`. Also be sure that in **Ubuntu Software** tab all check-boxes are ticked.
   - Then <kbd>Close</kbd> the **Software Sources** Window and execute this command to update your repository:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     ```
2. Now remove any **residual config** and others junked packages. Following commands will help you:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

   I want you to go for 4th step first without going for 3rd step. If it works then you don't have to upgrade you system, ie, you can skip the 3rd step.
3. Follow command will help you to upgrade your system.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   If you have finished this step, then also you've to go for 4th step. :)
4. These commands will help you to re-configure the packages installed. Execute these in your terminal:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
   ```

   <sub>This command would take some time around 3-5 minutes so wait. It will not give any output if executed successfully or else it will give the error message. Note down the error message if you get any.</sub>

   ```
   sudo update-grub && sudo initramfs -u
   ```

Then finally restart your system once. Hope it would help you to solve your issue.

Reply if something goes wrong or you get any error at any particular command with describing the command and the error message.

Comment: By upgrade, I want to stay at 12.04, do you mean upgrade to 12.04.3 or to 13.xx?

Comment: @durron597: Yes I kept it in my mind that you want to stick with **12.04**. That is why in first step I asked you to select **For long-term support versions**. :)

Comment: This seems like a pretty drastic approach; would be better if we could fix the single issue here.

Comment: @JeremyKerr: I know you are scared of the command: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` :) You can skip that command alone and continue with the remaining. I've also mentioned that **3rd** step would not be necessary and you can skip it completely if all works well without going through it.. What ever the steps I mentioned will not harm your system, just it will **re-configure** it. Only thing is that you've to believe me..

Comment: @JeremyKerr and Saurav Kumar, I did this and it didn't fix the problem. I also updated the BIOS with no luck.