# Upgraded Hardware-Enablement-Stack on 12.04. Nvidia isn't working, and won't install

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, hardware-enablement-stack

There also seem to be some weird behaviours related to the network (taking a very long time to pull updates, but also load webpages, etc.)

Note: I can't do a full update to 14.04 for work reasons. Is there an easy way to roll back this update? Or to fix whatever might be ailing it?

Note: When I go to install nvidia-304 (say) directly, it gives me an error that there are unmet dependencies on xorg-video-abi

Comment: Just to check, did you run a command similar to the one in [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/338785/241580) answer?

Comment: Similar to @saiarcot895, what commands, if any, did `hwe-support-status` recommend running to perform the upgrade?

Comment: I didn't do it through command line. I did it via the update manager GUI. I've just finished kind-of reinstalling 12.04.4 and the button to update the HWE stack is present now, but I'm kind of letting it be and reading through some of these other problems and comment threads.

Comment: It now says:

Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support
on 08/07/2014.  After this date security updates for critical parts (kernel
and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be available.

For more information, please see:
http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade 

OR

* Install a newer HWE version by running:
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty